# Need help writing a query (LEFT JOIN)

Tags: sql

There are research Proposals. Decisions are made on Proposals. Decisions can only be of 4 types. I need to display the latest decision on all reviewed proposals, associated with a certain researcher. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT p.ProposalID
    ,p.Title
    ,p.DATE
    ,p.Submitted
    ,p.ReviewCompleted
    ,d.DecisionID
    ,dt.Description AS Decision
FROM Proposal p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Decision
    ORDER BY DATE
    ) d
    ON d.ProposalID = p.ProposalID
LEFT JOIN DecisionType dt
    ON dt.DecisionTypeID = d.DecisionTypeID
WHERE p.ReviewCompleted = '1'
    AND p.ProposalID IN (
        SELECT ProposalID
        FROM Proposal
        WHERE ResearcherID = ?
        )
ORDER BY d.DATE
```

I understand that the problem comes from the first left join, but I can't figure out gow to get onlt the latest decision on p.ProposalID. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: If you could give the error message you receive, and even perhaps the sql for creating the tables, it would assist in debugging for you. Thanks

Comment: There's no error, I just don't get the right output. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Show us sample table data, the current incorrect result, and the expected result!

Comment: "I understand that the problem comes from the first left join" - what problem? you never described one.

Comment: AND p.ProposalID IN ( SELECT ProposalID  FROM Proposal WHERE ResearcherID = ? )   P is proposal.  You don't think you could just use p.ResearcherID = ?

Comment: And use specific columns you need over *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you use MSSQL (add it to tags if so). In this case rewrite this LEFT JOIN using [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Decision
    ORDER BY DATE
    ) d
    ON d.ProposalID = p.ProposalID
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Decision.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProposalID ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS Row_num
    FROM Decision
    ) d
    ON (d.ProposalID = p.ProposalID)
       AND (Row_num = 1)
```

Here you need to calculate row numbers for each group and order by date. Then select only first (`Row_num = 1`) for each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write this query using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
FROM Proposal p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Decision d
      WHERE d.ProposalID = p.ProposalID
      ORDER BY DATE DESC
     ) d LEFT JOIN
     DecisionType dt
     ON dt.DecisionTypeID = d.DecisionTypeID
```

`OUTER APPLY` is SQL Server's implementation of a "lateral join".  Sometimes, queries using `APPLY` have performance advantages.

Comment: Looks like alias missing. `FROM Decision d`